# Removing the default toolbar in an activity android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, themes

Before upgrading to `android 3.1`.I usually just change the theme to a theme. app compact. `NoTitleBar` but the new version of `android studio` is having errors recognizing it.I solved this problem by adding base to the beginning. But I can seem to find any answer regarding a style theme that supports removing the custom bar.

Comment: You can just use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and it'll work, even if `Theme` is in red.

Answer (score 2):

In your `res/values/styles.xml` you have this similar block of code. 
Ensure that you use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as `parent` of your theme

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Add this style in style file . where other styles are mentioned . 


<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/lightgreycolor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had to change parent theme in res/values/themes.xml

[image]