# Remove Action Bar to make a PopUp

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to remove Action Bar from the 2nd activity i've created but I didn't get this. Below is the Code of AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".popup_for_table" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

</application>
```

Below is the code of Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="PopUp" >


        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
```

[I want to Remove this Action Bar with Dark Background and text Table Generator , Picture is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y20mr.png)

Comment: Where is code for `PopUp`? Are you using a Dialog or an Activity ? Add your code ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the default toolbar in an activity android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358998/removing-the-default-toolbar-in-an-activity-android)

Comment: have you tried `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: I didn't done the code for pop up yet

Comment: After the action bar with the name on head removed, I'll create this layout with no action bar to pop up

Comment: I've tried {android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"} But it will remove the action bar of Main_activity but not the second_activity

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do like.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And set this new theme to your second activity.

```
<activity android:name=".popup_for_table" android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```

**NOTE: Check in your activity layout xml file. you should not use** `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

Comment: Sorry didn't work for me any changes required to java or design file

Comment: Still No Changes

Comment: I am not sure but code is correct if you following my instruction have you tried with creating new application may be this is your project specific issue. If it's working in new project then please share your project updated files.

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml add

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

In youe AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".popup_for_table" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: Sorry didn't work for me any changes required to java or design file